# Issue with handling large byte array on WCF service side

Tags: wcf

Good afternoon. There is a problem passing a large array size in a request to a WCF service.
I am getting an error:: The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

All the answers I found boil down to increasing maxArrayLength in the web.config file, but it doesn't help.

My config.file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
      <extensions>
          <behaviorExtensions>
              <add name="EdmBehaviorExtensionElement" type="Bis.Edm.Service.Interceptors.EdmBehaviorExtensionElement, Bis.Edm.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          </behaviorExtensions>
      </extensions>

      <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="EdmInspertorBehavior">
              <EdmBehaviorExtensionElement />
          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
          <binding name="basicHttpsBinding_Edm" closeTimeout="00:01:30" openTimeout="00:01:30"  sendTimeout="00:01:30" receiveTimeout="00:01:30"
                   messageEncoding="Mtom"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="Transport" />
          </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
     
  </bindings>

  <services>
      <service name="Bis.Edm.Service.EdmService">
          <endpoint binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="Bis.Edm.Service.IEdmService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsBinding_Edm" behaviorConfiguration="EdmInspertorBehavior"/>
      </service>
  </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

My service request model:

```
[DataContract]
public class EdmRequestModel
{
        [DataMember]
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

PS. If you pass a small array in the request, everything works fine

Please tell me where I make a mistake, please forgive me for my possible mistakes in the text :)

Comment: Noticed one feature, if you remove the behaviorConfiguration from the endpoint, then the parameters that are specified in the binding are applied. Otherwise, the parameters in the binding, namely readerQuotas, are ignored.

Comment: Will deleting behaviorConfiguration report an error?

Comment: When deleting behaviorConfiguration, no errors are observed, there are suspicions that bindings are ignored using customBehavior, namely <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
But I need to use customBehavior too :)

Thanks

Comment: You can try using the `MaxItervemsInObjectGraph` property.`<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors><serviceBehaviors><behavior name="***">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
</system.serviceModel>`